# Change the default time of inactivity required to lock screen

Tags: greeter

In Ubuntu and Mint, I can tweak the default inactive time before the screen turns off and my computer is locked. How do i change the default time of inactivity after which the screen gets locked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open system settings > power
There you can find everything about turning off the screen, adjusting sleep mode, ect.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install `dconf-editor` with `sudo apt install dconf-editor` in a terminal.
2. Navigate to org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power using the panel on the left.
3. There are four entries that are of interest to you - `sleep-inactive-ac-timeout`, `sleep-inactive-ac-type`, `sleep-inactive-battery-timeout`, `sleep-inactive-battery-type`.  The `ac` and `battery` refers to behaviour when a laptop is plugged in or on battery (if desktop, I assume the `ac` would apply). If you click one of the `type` options the drop-down menu will display the possible actions - you'll want `suspend` I think.
4. The `timeout` option is how long a period of inactivity (in seconds) is required before the action is carried out.  Simply click on the number there at present (probably 0), and replace with the desired value.